# Remove duplicated lines

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I need some help with transforming broken logs, I receive from my admins (unfortunately they not gonna fix it).
Basically, sometimes log contains duplicated first column, that I want to remove if another column has a value equal to null.

This is how it pretty much looks

```
datetime,auth_protocol,result,client,port,login
2016-07-15 09:34:52,www,PASS,111.222.333.444,5593,someAddress@domain.com
2016-07-15 09:34:52,www,PASS,111.222.333.444,NULL,someAddress@domain.com
2016-08-14 00:51:35,www,PASS,NULL,19509,someAddress@domain.com
2016-08-14 00:51:35,www,PASS,444.333.222.111,19509,someAddress@domain.com
2016-09-16 05:08:46,www,FAIL,123.456.789.222,45673,someAddress@domain.com
2016-09-16 15:35:55,www,FAIL,123.456.789.222,NULL,someAddress@domain.com
2016-09-17 17:10:01,www,FAIL,111.222.333.444,55516,someAddress@domain.com
```

As you can see, some lines have duplicated first column (date).

What I'm trying to do, is to:

1: For all columns, that first column is duplicated, compare 4 or 5 column (IP or Port)

2: Delete duplicated line with a null value in a column 4 or 5

This sould be the correct output:

```
datetime,auth_protocol,result,client,port,login
2016-07-15 09:34:52,www,PASS,111.222.333.444,5593,someAddress@domain.com
2016-08-14 00:51:35,www,PASS,444.333.222.111,19509,someAddress@domain.com
2016-09-16 05:08:46,www,FAIL,123.456.789.222,45673,someAddress@domain.com
2016-09-16 15:35:55,www,FAIL,123.456.789.222,NULL,someAddress@domain.com
2016-09-17 17:10:01,www,FAIL,111.222.333.444,55516,someAddress@domain.com
```

I hope it sounds clear;d

Comment: You can show us some code on what you tried.

Comment: Do duplicated lines always follow each other directly in the log?  Is there ever a case where column 4 or 5 contains a NULL and it's not a duplicated line?

Comment: 1) yes, always
2) yes, NULL value can be present like I showed in the correct example

Comment: @Inian, I made some ugly ad hoc, but its ugly;)

cat account.csv | grep -Ff <(cat account.csv | cut -d ',' -f1 | sort | uniq -d) | grep -v ",NULL," >> temp.csv;

while read line; do 
single=$(echo $line | cut -d "," -f1);
if [[ $(cat temp.csv | grep  "$single") == "" ]] ; then
echo $line >> temp.csv; fi
done < account.csv

Comment: @Wyjun, please put the code you tried into the actual question. You'll get more responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By doing two iterations over the log file, you can collect all used dates in the first iteration. And then remove NULL logs if the date is already used in the second iteration:

```
$ awk -F, '$4$5 !~ /NULL/ {d[$1]=1}
           NR == FNR { next }
           !d[$1] || $4$5 !~ /NULL/' input.log input.log
```

The the first iteration `d` gets populated with used dates from rows that doesn't contain `NULL` in the specified fields.

`NR == FNR` is only true for the first file iterated.

In the second iteration lines will be printed if they do not contain `NULL` in column 4 nor 5. Or if `d` doesn't contain the used date.

Comment: eyyy, what you copying my $4$5 for!

Comment: @123 I realized that there was no reason to be to safe as OP stated those two columns contains IP and Port, I would never do this if they wore alphanumeric columns.

Comment: @andlrc Lol you just copied my answer, 0% chance you would have 'realised', had i not posted with it.

Comment: @123 I have it in my shell history. Removed it since I thought I would make a "safer" script. Then realized there was no need.

Answer (score 3):

You could use this awk.

Iterate over the file twice.
Count dupes first time.
Print line that aren't dupes or don't contain NULL the second.

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$1]++;next}a[$1]<2||$4$5!~/NULL/' file{,}

datetime,auth_protocol,result,client,port,login
2016-07-15 09:34:52,www,PASS,111.222.333.444,5593,someAddress@domain.com
2016-08-14 00:51:35,www,PASS,444.333.222.111,19509,someAddress@domain.com
2016-09-16 05:08:46,www,FAIL,123.456.789.222,45673,someAddress@domain.com
2016-09-16 15:35:55,www,FAIL,123.456.789.222,NULL,someAddress@domain.com
2016-09-17 17:10:01,www,FAIL,111.222.333.444,55516,someAddress@domain.com
```

Comment: This will fail if there is two NULL rows that share the same date, which doesn't also have a valid record associated. It is however not necessarily a case to worry about.

Comment: @andlrc Just wrote it for the question requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in a single pass with a short script solution in bash utilizing arrays. (depending on the length of the file, you may find a double pass with `awk` faster, but for larger files, this version may be advantageous). The script simply reads all lines, but defers printing the each line until it has read the next and made a comparison of the date/times to determine if there is a possible duplicate entry. If the date/times are equal, then it checks the IP field. If the IP is `NULL` it skips printing that line.

This is just one approach of many. Give it a try with your data:

**Edit** test added for `NULL` in `id` field

```
#!/bin/bash

fn="${1:-/dev/stdin}"   ## read file or stdin

prevln=""   ## previous line & prev and curr arrays of values
declare -a prev=( ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' )
declare -a curr
declare -i iddup=0  ## flag marking duplicate in 'id' field

IFS=$' ,\t\n'   ## add ',' to internal field separator

while read -r line || test -n "$line"; do   ## read each line
    curr=( $(echo $line) )  ## fill current array with values
    ## test prev date/time with curr date/time
    if [ "${prev[0]}" = "${curr[0]}" -a "${prev[1]}" = "${curr[1]}" ]; then
        if [ "${prev[4]}" != "NULL" ]; then     ## if prev IP != NULL print
            echo "$prevln"                      ## otherwise, skip print
        fi
        [ "${curr[5]}" = "NULL" ] && iddup=1 || iddup=0  ## flag id dup
    elif [ "$iddup" -eq '0' ]; then   ## if date/time inequal, print line
        [ -n "$prevln" ] && echo "$prevln"
    fi
    prevln="$line"      ## assign line to prevln
    prev=( ${curr[@]} ) ## assign curr to prev array
done <"$fn"

## same test for the last line after loop exits
curr=( $(echo $line) )
if [ "${prev[0]}" = "${curr[0]}" -a "${prev[1]}" = "${curr[1]}" ]; then
    if [ "${prev[4]}" = "NULL" ]; then
        echo "$line"
    elif [ "${curr[4]}" = "NULL" ]; then
        echo "$prevln"
    else
        echo "$prevln"
    fi
else    ## if date/time inequal, print line
    [ -n "$prevln" ] && echo "$prevln"
fi
```

**Input File**

```
$ cat dat/log.txt
2016-07-15 09:34:52,www,PASS,111.222.333.444,5593,someAddress@domain.com
2016-07-15 09:34:52,www,PASS,111.222.333.444,NULL,someAddress@domain.com
2016-08-14 00:51:35,www,PASS,NULL,19509,someAddress@domain.com
2016-08-14 00:51:35,www,PASS,444.333.222.111,19509,someAddress@domain.com
2016-09-16 05:08:46,www,FAIL,123.456.789.222,45673,someAddress@domain.com
2016-09-16 15:35:55,www,FAIL,123.456.789.222,NULL,someAddress@domain.com
2016-09-17 17:10:01,www,FAIL,111.222.333.444,55516,someAddress@domain.com
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ bash logdups.sh <dat/log.txt
2016-07-15 09:34:52,www,PASS,111.222.333.444,5593,someAddress@domain.com
2016-07-15 00:51:35,www,PASS,444.333.222.111,19509,someAddress@domain.com
2016-09-16 05:08:46,www,FAIL,123.456.789.222,45673,someAddress@domain.com
2016-09-16 15:35:55,www,FAIL,123.456.789.222,NULL,someAddress@domain.com
2016-09-17 17:10:01,www,FAIL,111.222.333.444,55516,someAddress@domain.com
```

Comment: Didn't exactly work out. First two lines are duplicated:)

Comment: Hmm. Are you using the same data? I had no issue with your test data. I'll double check. I even added your headings and it was fine with the test data. Post the first two lines that are being duplicated and I'll sort it out. (are you also considering the `NULL` in the ID (following the IP field) as indicating a duplicate? (that's it, I looked at your data again, hold on I'll add that check)

Comment: @Wyjun OK, give it a shot now. I added the test for `NULL` in the `id` field. I didn't consider that as a duplicate condition to begin with.

Comment: yep, now it's fine! Thank U very much:) Appreciate

Comment: There are always multiple ways to skin the "proverbial cat" in bash and with shell tools. Just find one that meets your requirements and isn't too slow and call it good. Glad I was able to show you an alternate way to skin this one `:)`